# NSIS SetDateSave not preserving the creation/modified date of files installed in .nsi file

Tags: date, dll, installation, exe, nsis

I am using the SetDateSave function in several places in my .nsi file

However once the installer is run the all files date modified/created field is updated to the current time.

Any ideas?? I know that commands in .nsi files will only effect every line below the command. I am guessing that there is some other command further down that is overriding the SetDateSave, but I need a second opinion please!

Update:
I think the nsisunz it the culprit! Testing ZipDLL instead. Will update answer here if I solve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the zip format that was resetting the date modified field!

Simply used ZipDLL instead of nsisunzip!

Hope this helps someone in the future :)